# Create JS files dynamically with Yeoman

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to make a Yeoman generator to easily create controller files for Angular with this EXACT template, problem is I can't figure out how to create it with the function name dynamically, like: myangularjs:controller main (main as function name). Is this even possible?

Thanks

```
   (function() {
     "use strict";

     function Config($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider.when("", {
         controller: "<%= name %>",
         templateUrl: "",
         resolve: "<%= name %>".resolve
     });
     }

     function <%= name %>Ctrl() {

     }

     <%= name %>Ctrl.resolve = {};

     angular.module("App.Overview")
            .controller("'<%= name %>'Ctrl", [<%= name %>Ctrl])
            .config(["$routeProvider", Config]);
    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the angular generator, short answer for you is YES.

Here's how it will look like

```
angular.module('<%= scriptAppName %>')
  .controller('<%= classedName %>Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

And have a look at the 'Sub Generators' section [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-yeoman-generator--cms-20040)